# Nightwatch Page Object

Tags: nightwatch.js, pageobjects

Unable to find page objects, what am I missing here?

> Nightwatch 0.9.16

In nightwatch.json

```
"page_objects_path": "pages",
```

In actual folder

```
\pages\MyLegacyPage.js
```

In MyLegacyPage.js

```
module.exports = {
  myPauseMethod: function (browser) {
    browser.pause(1000);
    return this;
  }
};
```

In test

```
describe('CTA', function () {
    it('page objects tests', function (browser) {
        console.log('browser.page.MyLegacyPage() = ' + JSON.stringify(browser.page.MyLegacyPage()));
        var myPageObject = browser.page.MyLegacyPage();
        myPageObject.myPauseMethod(browser);
    });
});
```

Output

```
browser.page.MyLegacyPage() = {}
TypeError: myPageObject.myPauseMethod is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example of POM might help you solve your issue:

```
var dashCommands = {

    uploadAvatar:function(){
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@profileIcon', TIMEOUT)
            .click('@profileIcon')
            .waitForElementVisible('@avatarUpload', TIMEOUT)
            .moveToElement('@avatarUpload', 0,0)
            .click('@avatarUpload')
            .waitForElementVisible('@profileImageUploadOverlay', TIMEOUT)
            .assert.visible('@closeButton')
            .click('@selectPicture')

    }


module.exports = {
    commands:[dashCommands],
    elements: {
        dashLogo : { selector: 'div.topbar__title-wrap.topbar-title > h1'},
        profileAvatar: { selector: 'span:nth-child(4) > div > img'},
        searchField: { selector: 'div.topbar__search-feald-wrap > input'},
        topicsColumn: { selector: 'div.inner-dashboard-wrap.topic-wrap'},
        conclusionsColumn: { selector: 'div.inner-dashboard-wrap.conclusion-wrap'},
        messagesColumn: { selector: 'div.inner-dashboard-wrap.messages-wrap'},
        bookmarksColumn: { selector: 'div.inner-dashboard-wrap.request-wrap'},
        profileIcon: { selector: 'span:nth-child(4) > div'},
        avatarUpload: {selector: '//*[@id="profile-section"]/div[1]/div[1]/img', locateStrategy: 'xpath' },
        selectPicture: { selector: '#dialogContent_profile-image-modal'},
        profileImageUploadOverlay: { selector: '.layout-column button'},
        closeButton: { selector: '.ng-scope.icon-close'}
        },
}
```

which means you have to make your function inside the var and then you have to insert that commands with the following line of code in module.exports part: commands:[nameOfYourVar]

Comment: Thanks, I changed to enhanced object and it worked. When outputting page object, it's normal that it shows either '{}', or shows an error of 'it's a circular structure'